# The number of all multi-sets with cardinality $k$ over $\{1, ..., n\}$ is $n+k-1 \choose k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

> Let $k, n \in \Bbb N, n \ge 1$.
>
> Then, the number of all multi-sets with cardinality $k$ over $\{1, ..., n\}$ is $n+k-1 \choose k$.

**Proof:**

Let $A$ be the set of all multisets with cardinality $k$ over subsets of $\{1, ..., n\}$. Let $B$ be the set of all subsets of cardinality $k$ over $\{1, ..., n + k - 1\}$. We define

$$\phi: A \rightarrow B$$

$$\{a_1 \le \ ... \ \le a_k\} \rightarrow \{a_1, a_2 + 1, \ ... \, a_k + k - 1\}.$$

Let

$$1 \le a_1 < a_2 + 1 < \ ... \ < a_k + k - 1 \le n + k - 1,$$

hence, $\phi$ is well-defined.

Let

$$\psi: B \rightarrow A$$

$${b_1 < \ ... \ < b_k} \rightarrow \{b_1, b_1 - 1, ..., b_k - k + 1\}.$$

We see that $\psi$ is well-defined and that it is the inverse function of $\phi$. Since there exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$, we have

$$|A| = |B| = {n+k-1 \choose k}.$$

**Questions:**

1. Why we do need to define $\phi$ like this? It looks kind of arbitrary to me.
2. Why do we need to define $\psi$ like this?
3. Besides that, I don't see how $\psi$ is indeed the inverse function of $\phi$. Plus, isn't $B$ just a normal set and $A$ is the multiset here? So why does $\psi$ map from something that looks like  multi-set into something that looks like a normal set?

Answer (score 1):

The proof looks absolutely fine to me. You built a bijection (pairing) between elements from $A$ and elements from $B$. These pairs look as follows:

$$a \leftrightarrow \varphi(a)), \quad a \in A$$

Or, either way,

$$\psi(b) \leftrightarrow b, \quad b \in B$$

We define $\varphi$ in such a way that it is invertible. In particular, the following should hold:

1. $\varphi(a)$ is defined for all $a \in A$
2. For different $a_1 \neq a_2$ from $A$: $\varphi(a_1) \neq \varphi(a_2)$
3. For any $b \in B$ there should exist $a$ such that $\varphi(a) = b$

Your function $\varphi$ satisfies all these conditions. Thus, elements from $A$ and elements from $B$ can be paired.

In this case, we can obtain an explicit form of inverse function for $\varphi$, e.g. such a function $\psi$ that:
$$\psi(\varphi(a)) = a, \quad a \in A$$

Here $\psi$ should map all elements from $B$ to $A$ and can be defined as you mentioned in your proof.

Answer (score 1):

We essentially want to find the size of $A$, denoted as $|A|$. If we can prove $|A| = |B|$ and find $|B|$ at the same time, we then are able to find the size of $A$. In order to prove that $|A| = |B|$, one way is to prove that there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$; that is, there is a function $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ such that

- for each $a \in A$, $\phi(a) \in B$;
- for $a' \neq a$, it is guaranteed that $\phi(a') \neq \phi(a)$

**The existence of $\phi$ shows that $|A| \leq |B|$.** Similarly, there is a function $\psi: B \rightarrow A$ to complete the bijection.

The $\phi$ and $\psi$ functions defined in the questions constitute a bijection between $A$ and $B$ and thus we can conclude that $|A| = |B|$. To see that $\psi$ and $\phi$ are inverse to each other, observe that
$$
\psi(\phi(\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_k\})) = \psi(\{a_1, a_2 + 1, \cdots, a_k + k - 1\}) = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_k\}
$$
and
$$
\phi(\psi(\{b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_k\})) = \phi(\{b_1, b_2 - 1, \cdots, b_k - k + 1\}) = \{b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_k\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate proof that  the reader may want to consult. Using
the cycle  index of the unlabeled multiset  operator $\mathfrak{M}$ we
obtain the generating function

$$Z(S_k)(A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_n).$$

We have by the exponential formula  for the desired cycle index of the
symmetric group

$$Z(S_k) = [w^k] \exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} a_l \frac{w^l}{l}\right).$$

Doing the substitution we find

$$[w^k] \exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1}
(A_1^l+A_2^l+\cdots+A_n^l) \frac{w^l}{l}\right).$$

We are  only interested in  the count so  we may set the  variables to
one, getting

$$[w^k] \exp\left(n \sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{w^l}{l}\right)
= [w^k] \exp\left(n \log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)
= [w^k] \frac{1}{(1-w)^n} \\= {k+n-1\choose k}.$$

This is the claim.